# Appium. How to findElement on activity that has `android:launchMode="singleInstance"` flag?

Tags: android, automated-tests, appium, webdriver-io

I've faced with issue while creating automated test for native android app (using appium from webdriver.io + typescript).

Currently I'm trying to click on button by id on activity that has `android:launchMode="singleInstance"` in android manifest.

I've faced with issue that appium cannot find any element on this activity.
Log looks like:

```
[debug] [JSONWP Proxy] Proxying [POST /elements] to [POST http://localhost:8203/wd/hub/session/8938c098-48e6-4e7b-b9fd-4cf69034058c/elements] with body: {"strategy":"id","selector":"callStatus","context":"","multiple":true}
[debug] [JSONWP Proxy] Got response with status 200: {"sessionId":"8938c098-48e6-4e7b-b9fd-4cf69034058c","status":0,"value":[]}
[debug] [MJSONWP] Responding to client with driver.findElements() result: []
```

BTW. I cannot inspect that activity using UIAutomatorView, looks like the issue is related also to it.

if remove `android:launchMode="singleInstance"` flag - all will work fine.

How to solve this issue?

How to find element on activity that has `android:launchMode="singleInstance"` flag?

Answer (score 0):

If driver fails to find element, check what XML structure it face at the moment: [driver.source()](http://webdriver.io/api/protocol/source.html)

Maybe it will return XML representation of other activity/fragment. 
You can also double check the number of contexts you got at the moment: [driver.contexts();](http://webdriver.io/api/mobile/contexts.html)

If there are more than 1 NATIVE_APP context, then you may need to switch the other one.

Comment: tnx for advice. will check

Comment: Unfortunately there is only one context =(

Comment: What about driver.source() output? Do you elements from your current screen or previous one?

Comment: Actually I've found the reason of Appium failures.
Just increased waitForExist timeout to 20 seconds (previously was 10) due to some weird behaviour Activity is displayed but Appium cannot find any element for 10 sec.